# Why the following nested loop is not vectorized?

Tags: c++, nested-loops, simd

[gcc godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#) of the code.

The gcc godbolt shows the code uses the `imul` instruction of i386, instead of something like `_mm_mul_ps`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
  int A[2400];
  int B[12];
  int iA, iB;

  //version 3
  for(iA = 0; iA < 200*3*4; iA+=1200){
    for(iB = 0; iB < 3*4; ++iA, ++iB){
      A[iA]*=B[iB];
    }   
  }
  for(iA = 0; iA < 200*3*4; iA++){
    cout<<A[iA];
  }
}
```

Comment: how can it be vectorised? It contains I/O.

Comment: i see. After I remove the I/O, I find gcc still doesn't automatically vectorize.

Comment: if you remove the iA += 1200 it vectorises

Comment: thanks. it vectorizes now.

Comment: Your godbolt link looks like you just hit ctrl-L to copy the URL from the title bar.  Look at the URL you used: `https://gcc.godbolt.org/#`.  Use the "Full Link" button on godbolt to get a non-shortened URL.  Also, if the `iA += 1200` was just a typo / bug, you might want to delete this question.